# Как реализовать пустой ввод, используя java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность получить пустой токен в java.util.Scanner?
Например, я установил разделитель "]". Использую метод next(), ввожу один этот символ и ничего не происходит, то есть так как до разделителя ничего нет, он не попадает в токен. Если я введу повторно, то поймает перенос строки и ввод засчитается. Моя же цель заключается в том, чтобы после ввода разделителя ввод прекратился бы сразу, чтобы не было необходимости что-либо вставлять перед разделителем. То есть, реализовать пустой ввод.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter("]");
    String input = scanner.next();
    
    scanner.close();
    
    System.out.println(input);
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете использовать метод `nextLine()` и разделитель 'пробел'. Либо просто ввести 'пробел' перед вашим разделителем.

Comment: пока что у меня на ум ничего другого и не приходит :)

Answer (score 0):

Введите два разделителя подряд и у вас будет пустой токен.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner("]]").useDelimiter("]")) {
        String input = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("'" + input + "' is empty? " + input.isEmpty());
    }        
}
```

```
'' is empty? true
```

Comment: почему, если использовать разделитель "\\s", то нет необходимости его дублировать?

Comment: Что значит _не нужно дублировать_? Чтобы прочитать пустой токен, нужно как минимум иметь **два** делимитера (в случае пробельных символов `\s` вторым делимитером может быть любой другой пробельный символ, включая перевод строки, табуляцию и т.п.), иначе сканеру будет нечего читать и `scanner.next()` выбросит `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.  Можно проверить для кода `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(" \n").useDelimiter("\s")`